# Can you work with Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) using Windows for Android part?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I wanted to enable one of my Android project to the new KMM but will deploy only for Android platform for the time being. According to this [FAQ page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-faq.html#what-is-the-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-plugin) it seems that the plugin works only for macOS. But was confused on the next paragraph stating

> The good news is that you can work with cross-platform projects on
> Android even without the Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin. If you
> are going to work with shared code or Android-specific code, you can
> work on any operating system supported by Android Studio.

I am not planning yet to run the iOS part as I am still learning it, all I want for now is to prepare my project so when I am confident with my iOS skill starting it would be easy. I do not have a good Mac device as of now that is why I prefer to use my Windows machine for now which is more reliable for heavy stuff like Android development.

Comment: Yes, Kotlin multiplatform for Android works fine in Windows

Comment: @TylerV but set up should be done first with Mac right? Or I can also start the setup using the plugin in Windows?

Comment: Nope, it can be done fully on Windows. Source: I used it solely in Windows for awhile before later buying a Mac and adding an iOS app.

Comment: There should be a KMM template in Android Studio you can use to create it on a Windows machine easily. I think that FAQ is about the iOS KMM plugin, not KMM in general.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the right place and reference and it is possible according to this [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-setup.html)